# How to setup fonts in Linux subsystem?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use the Linux subsystem for windows (a bit of an adventure for me not knowing Linux). I've installed [starship.rs](https://starship.rs/) and noticed I've got a number of badly rendering symbols. I've read that I need a powerline font so I've tried installing them and firacode (my preference).

I've however found that even after doing so I'm still getting errors rendering the characters.

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be missing? Ultimately I want to be able to swap out my git-bash for bash (in linux) within ConEmu if it's relevant.

Comment: Why use ConEmu instead of the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)?

Comment: He *is* using WSL though? Just not with the standard Windows Terminal, which sucks. // WSL does not do the rendering. In your case, that’s ConEmu. So ConEmu is at fault here. I recommend using mintty/wsltty instead.

Comment: @DanielB sorry, I should mention that currently my testing is using `cmd` and running `bash` inside it. Though I have the same results in ConEmu

Comment: Did you install powerline using `https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/install.ps1` ?

Comment: See https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2019/10/05/have-a-great-looking-terminal-and-a-more-effective-shell-with-oh-my-zsh-on-wsl-2-using-windows/ for some screenshots on how to configure powershell font, and if it works for you, please post an answer summarizing your solution.

Comment: @ssnobody I've tried installing that way just now too - that doesn't seem to have worked. Just reading to see if I want to try zsh

Comment: On a side note... be advised that using Linux's git under WSL1 is slower than sin.  I alias the windows git.exe to git to make it faster.  There is also a new windows terminal app (beta) in the windows store that does tabs like ComEmu and doesn't suck.

Comment: For me, I installed the `fonts-firacode` package in the WSL instance and installed a Nerdfont on Windows from https://www.nerdfonts.com/ . I went to the terminal emulator settings and set the fonts to the installed Nerdfont on my wsl profile and it worked. I know this might be not the exact solution for your problem, because it uses the Terminal app and more, but it works. *This is the "great" Microsoft Windows we are talking about, what do you except? :(*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR; 
You need to install  windows host and configure Powerline fonts bash gui properties.

found info [here](http://iamnotmyself.com/2017/04/15/setting-up-powerline-shell-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)

> you actually need to install these fonts in Windows and set the console host font to one of them.
>
> Next open bash and click the icon in the upper left corner and select Properties. Change to the Font tab and select one of the patched fonts you just installed. They will all say "for Powerline" so just pick one of those.

Comment: there is slightly better and straight forward way to use this. Using [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) and change shell to Ubuntu Bash. Why ? Glad you asked. MobaXterm comes preinstalled with Powerline fonts Zsh configured out of the box. so rendering powerline fonts is included in it.

Comment: Not quite got there, but it's certainly an improvement. Wanted to accept so bounty doesn't get wasted while I keep trying.

Comment: @Ian, I am interested to know what exactly didn't work? Any specific things which did not work ?

Comment: sure - I think `powerline-shell` has moved on a bit since. So I couldn't run the `cat` command or the `install.py` as described. I tried using `setup.py` instead to no avail. I also came across https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAPrettyPromptInWindowsTerminalWithPowerlineNerdFontsCascadiaCodeWSLAndOhmyposh.aspx which is a lot newer, but that doesn't seem to be working either in the Ubuntu console or ConEmu which is odd. I just get square boxes instead of powerline symbols despite having re-configured the fonts.

Comment: can you answer 1. have toy installed fronts on windows host? 2. have reconfigured your bash terminal or ConEmu for powerline fonts 3. can you please try [this](https://gist.github.com/gdetrez/5845092) powerline test script to test powerline font. run it on both bashWSL and ConEmu. or `echo "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"`

Comment: ConEmu is not supported as per [FirCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-support)

Answer (score 3):

How I solved this:

1. Install "Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font" https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads
   Unpack -> Open "whatever font you like".ttf and install.
   Check the installed font in a directory "C:\Windows\Fonts".

2.1) Open "Powershell", "Ubuntu" (or another WSL-distro), then right-click -> Properties -> Font -> Change font to "Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font".

2.2) If you use Windows Terminal. Open it -> "Ctrl+," -> find an attribute "profiles{...} -> defaults{...} -> add to "defaults" an attribute "fontFace": "SauceCodePro Nerd Font" to apply the font to all profiles or choose a profile from "list" and type the same to apply only to the given profile (e.x. "Cascadia Code PL" for Powershell, "SauseCode Pro Nerd Font" for Ubuntu).

3. **Optional**. Open VSCode -> Ctrl+, -> fontFamily: type "SauseCodePro Nerd Font" **before** other fonts.
4. You can do this with other fonts, but they need to support a powerline glyphs, e.g. "Mononoki" font.

Comment: Step 2.1 didn't work, and the font didn't show up, even though the font was installed to C:\Windows\Fonts

Comment: Had the same problem like @CrazyVideoGamer Solved it by choosing the "... windows compatible" font.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup fonts in your WSL, you need to setup fonts in the host system, namely Windows.

Key points were in setup all powerline fonts in the host system; I noticed what some people tried to install `.\install.ps1` (PowerShell) the script of this [powerline repo](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) in WSL, but its script must be run in Windows PowerShell.

You have to change the execution policy on Windows 10.
I tried setup on base this [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-your-first-powershell-script-file-windows-10), and it works.

And so, you can just install fonts manually and not have all problems.

**Don't forget** to apply font for WSL in settings.json

I also noticed that some ligatures work very badly or don't render at all.

**Updated info:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup